# Merge objects/maps with mapstruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have two objects of the same type. All fields are `Map<String, SomeType>`, so the objects look like:

```java
class Obj {
  Map<String, TypeA> propA;
  Map<String, TypeB> propB;
  ...

  Obj setPropA(Map<String, TypeA> newMap) { ... }
  Obj setPropB(Map<String, TypeB> newMap) { ... }
  ...
 
  Obj putPropA(String key, TypeA a) { ... }
  Obj putPropB(String key, TypeB b) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I need to merge two of these objects by merging/concatenating all map entries (the string keys never clash). Currently, this is done by hand. But, that seems clumsy and the as the class is generated, as soon as a property is added, the merge is incomplete.

```java
Obj merge(Obj ob1, Obj ob2) {
  return new Obj()
    .setPropA(mergeMaps(ob1.getPropA(), ob2.getPropA()))
    .setPropB(mergeMaps(ob1.getPropB(), ob2.getPropB()))
    ...;
}

<T> Map<String, T> mergeMaps(Map<String, T> aMap, Map<String, T> bMap) {
  aMap.putAll(bMap);
  return aMap;
}
```

Can mapstruct be used to automatically merge all of the field maps?

Comment: How new entries are added to `propA` and `propB`,? Does `Obj` contain a method to add new entries to `propA` and `propB`?

Comment: Yes, there is a `putPropT(String key, T t)` method for each property map.

Comment: The code you have provided probably does not work. `propA` values are of type `TypeA` and `propB` values are of type `TypeB` while `mergeMaps` expects the values of both of the maps to be the same (`<T>`). Maybe they share the same superclass, then `<T>` would rather be `<T extends CommonSuperClass>`.

Comment: The code runs. `mergeMaps` is generic on the method, so each call has its own type. (It's defined outside of the Obj class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Mapper
public interface ObjMapper {

    ObjMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ObjMapper.class);
    
    Obj merge(Obj source, @MappingTarget Obj target);
    
    default <T> void mergeMaps(Map<String, T> source, @MappingTarget Map<String, T> target) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( target == null ) {
            target = new HashMap<>();
        }
        target.putAll(source);
    }
    
}
```

The generated code is:

```
public class ObjMapperImpl implements ObjMapper {

    @Override
    public Obj merge(Obj source, Obj target) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return target;
        }

        if ( source.getPropA() != null ) {
            if ( target.getPropA() == null ) {
                target.setPropA( new LinkedHashMap<String, ChildA>() );
            }
            mergeMaps( source.getPropA(), target.getPropA() );
        }
        else {
            target.setPropA( null );
        }
        if ( source.getPropB() != null ) {
            if ( target.getPropB() == null ) {
                target.setPropB( new LinkedHashMap<String, ChildB>() );
            }
            mergeMaps( source.getPropB(), target.getPropB() );
        }
        else {
            target.setPropB( null );
        }

        return target;
    }

}
```

the only difference is that it makes an update on target.
If you need to have a new object, you need to execute the merge method twice:

```
Obj newObj = new Obj();
newObj = ObjMapper.INSTANCE.merge(ob1, newObj); // add from ob1
newObj = ObjMapper.INSTANCE.merge(ob2, newObj); // add from ob2
```